# JS, WebPack, Not Dynamically Loading Images Using Phaser3 Beyond Preload Function For IO Game

Tags: javascript, webpack, networking, game-engine, phaser-framework

My attempts at making an IO game is failing, as I can't dynamically load images after I have packed the game using WebPack (a hypothesis). When I lazy load any assets whether it be cross origin or local, it doesn't seem to load and render.

in index.js I have this in phaser's create():

```
 this.load.image('arc_red', 'https://art.pixilart.com/187aec08b8014f7.gif');//testing with this   
    this.load.once('complete', ()=>{console.log('image loaded!')}, this);       
    this.load.start();
```

when I use the preload, it does work. But dynamically it does not. I've been searching for nearly a day straight without any luck.

question:

Is my assumption correct? And if it is, what is a way I can dynamically load images after WebPack has packed the files?

Comment: I have two question: What webserver are you running (the dev server of webpack or a different one)? And could you share your `webpack.config.js` ?

Comment: both the dev server and when I build the files do not work. I do not have a webpack.config.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no webpack expert *(and depending on the webpack version)*, but if you are not using a webpack.config, the default behavior is that there should be:

- **webpack** bundle files are placed into the `./dist` folder. *So to answer your question, any file that is not in this folder is not bundled with webpack*

> Except if they are "inlined" in the `main.js`, I think images are not be inlined automatically/without plugin, or atleast in the version I used to use.

- **dev-server** offers an extra folder, where "static" files can be placed, it is `./public`(https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/)

So all files that are served from the dev-server must be in on of those folders.

I would place the images/assets into that `./public` folder, and than they should be visible.

> **Info:** I tripped over this once, files placed in `./public` folder are accessed, as if they would be in the `./dist` folder.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Although I'm ignorant to the fact I don't understand what you mean by inlined files in main.js. If that is a way I can dynamically load images can you tell me more about it?

Comment: @IAmNoob the short answer is you can dynamically load images if you create a folder named `public` on the same level as `dist` and add the images into this folder. Or you can let webpack compress all files into a single `main.js`. the later is more complicated _(or atleast it was with webpack version 4.x)_, and I never used webpack 5+ here is the link to the Docs that are really good https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/. I hope this helps abit or someone else can give more advice.